# Vapor fluent doesn't throw upon violating foreign key constraint

Tags: swift, vapor

When I'm adding a model to the database using create, Vapor fluent doesn't throw an exception when one of the foreign keys is violated. It's also not inserted, the create function just returns as normal.

Is this the standard behavior of Vapor Fluent?

I'm using Vapor 3 with PostgreSQL.

This is my migration to add the foreign key constraints:

```
struct AddAddressForeignKeys: Migration {
    typealias Database = PostgreSQLDatabase

    static func prepare(on conn: PostgreSQLConnection) -> Future<Void> {
        return PostgreSQLDatabase.update(Address.self, on: conn) { builder in
            builder.reference(from: \.regionId, to: \CodeRegion.id)
            builder.reference(from: \.countryId, to: \CodeCountry.id)
        }
    }

    static func revert(on conn: PostgreSQLConnection) -> Future<Void> {
        return PostgreSQLDatabase.update(Address.self, on: conn) { builder in
            builder.deleteReference(from: \.regionId, to: \CodeRegion.id)
            builder.deleteReference(from: \.countryId, to: \CodeCountry.id)
        }
    }
}
```

Update: I've added enableReferences as mentioned in the answer of Jacob Relkin, but there's still no exception thrown. H

```
// Configure database
let config = PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig(hostname: "localhost", port: 5432, username: "postgres", database: "test", password: nil, transport: .cleartext)
let postgres = PostgreSQLDatabase(config: config)

// Register the configured database to the database config.
var databases = DatabasesConfig()
databases.add(database: postgres, as: .psql)
databases.enableReferences(on: .psql)
services.register(databases)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to enforce foreign key violations, you must call [`enableReferences(on:)`](https://github.com/vapor/fluent/blob/3.2.0/Sources/Fluent/Schema/DatabasesConfig%2BReferences.swift#L3-L5) on your `DatabasesConfig` when you set it up.

Comment: Okay thanks. What identifier is meant for parameter on: ? Is it the name of the database?

Comment: It's a [`DatabaseIdentifier`](https://github.com/vapor/database-kit/blob/master/Sources/DatabaseKit/Database/DatabaseIdentifier.swift)

Comment: Ah, it's .psql in case of a Postgres DB. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Unfortunatly, the problem is still present, there's no exception thrown. I've updated my question with the code to enable the references.

Comment: Okay, I just tried it again and now it work! Maybe there was some caching issue. Thanks!